# Definable subsets of $\mathbb{Q}^2$ in $\langle \mathbb{Q} , < \rangle$?

Tags: logic, model-theory

The question seems quite simple; what are the definable subsets of $\mathbb{Q}^2$ over the structure $\langle \mathbb{Q} , < \rangle$.

Part of me wants to say there are none, given any definable subset $S \subseteq \mathbb{Q}^2$ must be closed under automorphisms i.e if $(a,b) \in S$, $\pi$ an automorphism, then $\pi(a,b) = (\pi(a),\pi(b)) \in S$. However I can't find a way to compute such a map without also ruling out that $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is definable there.

Comment: Certainly the empty set and the entire structure are always definable, so "none" cannot be the right answer.

Comment: In your argument about automorphisms, you should have written $\pi(a,b) = (\pi(a),\pi(b)) \in \underline{\pi[}S\underline{]}$ (where I've underlined the omitted text). With that correction, there is no problem.

Comment: @RobArthan ... and the point is that $\pi[S] = S$, when $S$ is definable without parameters.

Comment: Yes, sure: in retrospect, I didn't understand the OP's last sentence (and still don't) and my comment is not pertinent. At least my answer to the question is correct! The approach via automorphisms does seem to solve this problem too.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: to be asked this question, you must have met the fact that $(\mathbb{Q}, <)$ admits quantifier-elimination: i.e., every formula is equivalent to a quantifier-free formula. So every definable subset of $\mathbb{Q}^2$ belongs to the Boolean algebra generated by the sets defined by $x = y$, $x < y$ and $y < x$.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to say a bit about the *parameter-free* case; working with parameters is trickier, and it's good to try to figure out how to get there from here. Also, I'm going to avoid quantifier elimination because working with automorphisms is more fun. :P

---

Your argument about automorphisms is in the right direction, althought the argument itself doesn't work. As Carl points out, $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{Q}^2$ are certainly definable. And there are two more trivial examples: the diagonal, $\Delta=\{(q, q): q\in\mathbb{Q}\}$, and the complement of the diagonal, $\overline{\Delta}$. But it doesn't even stop here: there are **nontrivial** definable subsets, like $\{(a, b): a<b\}$. So it's not going to be so easy!

But let's try to see how much we can rule out with automorphisms.

First, suppose $q\in\mathbb{Q}$; then the map $\pi_q: p\mapsto p+q$ is an automorphism of $\mathcal{Q}=(\mathbb{Q}, <)$, so if $D$ is a definable subset of $\mathcal{Q}^2$ we must have $\pi(D)=\{(\pi(p), \pi(q)): (p, q)\in D\}=D$.

Geometrically, this means that $D$ is a union of lines of slope 1. (Think about why.)

So we've ruled out a bunch of sets, but there's still a lot left; and certainly (since there are uncountable many unions of lines with slope 1) we haven't gotten rid of all the undefinable sets. So let's look for another class of automorphisms which will help kill off some bad sets.

In order to kill off more bad sets, our new automorphisms had better be quite different from the $\pi_q$s already considered. The obvious maps to look at are the *multiplicative* ones, in contrast with the *additive* nature of the $\pi_q$s: $$\rho_q: p\mapsto qp \quad \mbox{($q$ positive)}.$$

Now let's think about what these maps can do to a set $D\subseteq\mathbb{Q}^2$ which is a union of lines of slope 1. By applying an appropriate $\rho_q$ we can move the lines with slope 1 **above** the origin around however we like; and similarly with the lines of slope 1 **below** the origin.

I claim we're done!

- Figure out what sets this rules out;
- now show that all those sets are definable. (This will be much easier than it sounds.)

Comment: I probably know you, but I can't figure out who you are based on the questions you've asked and answered. Care to enlighten me, here in person? :0)

Comment: Hi Alex! It's Noah. :P

Comment: Ah! I should have guessed that, but I assumed you'd be Noah S here too.

Comment: Yeah, I should be, but I've never gotten around to merging the accounts. And yeah, you should have known it was me - none of my answers/questions were about computability theory! :P